# How to make POST request in recycler view adapter

Tags: android

I want to send POST request when a user clicks on button present in recycler view item.I am using OkHttp3 for making network requests when user clicks on button I am sending POST request to node server.
My problem is in OnResponse call of OkHttp3 I am unable to define runOnUiThread() method.

This is what I have done so far:

**MyPostedBookAdapter.java**

```
public class MyPostedBookAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyPostedBookAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<PostedModel> listItem;
Context context;
String id;
private static final String URI = "https:bookbudiapp.herokuapp.com/deleteRow";

public MyPostedBookAdapter(List<PostedModel> listItem, Context context){

    this.listItem = listItem;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyPostedBookAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.posted_book,viewGroup,false);


    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyPostedBookAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

    final PostedModel model =  listItem.get(i);

    id = model.getPostId();

    viewHolder.userBookName.setText(model.getPurchaseBookName());

    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.openbook);

    Glide.with(context).load(model.getPurchaseImage()).apply(requestOptions).into(viewHolder.userPostBook);

    viewHolder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(context,id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            deleteRow();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItem.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView userPostBook;
    TextView userBookName;
    Button delete;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        userPostBook = (itemView).findViewById(R.id.userPostBook);
        userBookName = (itemView).findViewById(R.id.userBookName);
        delete = (itemView).findViewById(R.id.delete);
    }
}

private void deleteRow(){

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                              .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                              .readTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                              .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                              .build();

    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder().add("postId",id).build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(URI).post(formBody).build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

    });

  }
}
```

Let me know how can define runOnUiThread() method in response call.
Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: You can call deleteRow method in the parent activity/Fragment with an interface

Comment: You are using `Context context;` rather than use the `Activity context;` and call `context.runOnUiThread()` anywhere from your `MyPostedBookAdapter` class.

Answer (score 0):

By Your activity context you can call runOnUiThread() in adapter classes.

Answer (score 0):

By observing the code you have posted here that you want to update UI after deleted data(Particuler Row On RecyclerView). Right ?

You are send date to node server  using Okhttp on **MyPostedBookAdapter.java** .
Now, Update To  UI you have to notifydatasetChanged on Adaper Row onResponse() Method.. Write this code . Hope this will help you.

```
private void deleteRow(){

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                              .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                              .readTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                              .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                              .build();

    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder().add("postId",id).build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(URI).post(formBody).build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        // To remome row from recyclerView Row(item).
        arrayList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, arrayList.size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

    });

  }
```

Where **position** is the particular row(item)'s position.To get Position you can use  **getAdapterPosition()** method.

```
position=ViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()
```

Any query comment here. This helps me .Hope this will also help you .Thanks...